# Reducing a graph without lowering its chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

While trying to find an algorithm to reduce a graph without lowering its chromatic number, I made the following algorithm (but not sure if it works):

1. Given a (simple) graph $G$, look for subgraphs of $m$ ($m \geq 2$) vertices, which are isomorphic to $K_m$ minus an edge, and whose unfilled edge (say, $e=(v_1,v_2)$) is still unfilled in $G$, i.e. $e\not\in E(G)$. Pick such a subgraph with maximal $m$, and then identify $v_1$ and $v_2$. After reducing some multiple edges to simple edges, we get a new simple graph $G'$ whose number of vertices is one less than that of $G$.
2. Repeat #1 until there is no such subgraph.

Let's call this algorithm "Highest dimension first folding (HDFF)". I wonder if HDFF always gives us $K_{\chi(G)}$, where $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of $G$, and $K_n$ is the complete graph on $n$ vertices.

Comment: I do not quite understand step 1, do you mean that you delete either $v_1$ or $v_2$ and all incident edges from $G$?

Comment: @lattice Nope. I mean "identifying"(=gluing) two vertices, not deleting any of them.

Comment: Oh okay, now I got it. Nice question, and I agree with Mosquite's second answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Your algorithm doesn't preserve the chromatic number (it cannot lower the chromatic number however) and this time I've found a correct reason.

Consider the graph,
[$G$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whLVv.png).
The vertices $v_1, v_2, x_1, x_2$ of $G$ create a $K_4$ with the edge between $v_1$ and $v_2$ missing. The largest $K_m - e$ in this graph has $m=3$ and one is given by $x_1, x_2, v_1, v_2$.

Applying (1) to this graph with $v_1$ and $v_2$ identified produces a graph with an induced $K_5$ subgraph. Therefore it has chromatic number at least 5. However, $G$ has chromatic number 4 as we can see from the coloring in the figure of $G$.

Comment: Nice example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm will result in a complete graph, but I think it doesn't preserve the chromatic number. The [Grötzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph), is the smallest graph with no triangles and chromatic number 4. The largest induced subgraph of the Grötzsch graph that is $K_m$ minus an edge has $m=3$. Applying (1) from your algorithm to any pair of nonadjacent vertices of the Grötzsch graph will result in a graph that has no triangles and is smaller than the the Grötzsch graph and thus has a different chromatic number.

EDIT: This is wrong. There are triangles in the resulting graph after applying (1). I'll look into this a little more later.

Comment: It seems that not ALL pair of nonadjacent vertices of the Grötzsch graph will result in a graph that has no triangles... Can you specify a pair? I cannot find one easily.

Comment: The Grötzsch graph itself already has no triangles, so applying (1) (possibly multiple times) will always result in a graph with no triangles, since (if I got (1) correctly) you are only removing vertices and edges. Also, any nonadjacent vertices are connected via a path of length 2, which yields a subgraph that is $K_3$ minus an edge, so it is possible to apply (1) at least once. Since the Grötzsch graph is the smallest graph with no triangles and chromatic number $4$, applying (1) once will give a graph with a smaller chromatic number. Thus, HDFF does not lead to $K_{\chi(G)}$ in this case.

Comment: Oops, on closer inspection I see that there is a triangle in the resulting graph. My bad.